# Strange visibility behavior CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a navigation bar that is fixed position top.  Inside it is a mailing list signup field.  When hovering over the containing div. jQuery slideDown is invoked revealing more input fields in the previously hidden DIV and then SlideUp is invoked when mousing out.  The trouble is that everything behaves in Firefox, but in IE7 the bottom (visible) portion of the div (which is absolutely positioned to bottom in order to keep at the bottom during slideDown and slideUp) is not visible on the initial page load.  Oddly, after hovering the (seemingly empty) div, the empty content mysteriously appears and then remains visible even after SlideUp and mouse out are complete.  Any ideas anyone (I'm pretty good with CSS but at a loss currently)?

```
<div id="top_mailing">
  <div id="top_mailing_hidden">
    <div id="drop_container">
      <form method="POST" id="top_email_form" action="xxx">
      <input type="hidden" name="xid" id="xid" value="ccb590470057fda47ff380f48196b203" />
      <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="CustomFormWeb" />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="Ranya.net Top Page Mailing List" />
      <br class="clear" />
      <div id="hidden_inputs">
        <div class="mailing_input">
          First Name*
          <input type='text' name='Contact0FirstName' value=''></div>
        <div class="mailing_input">
          Last Name
          <input type='text' name='Contact0LastName' value=''></div>
        <div class="mailing_input">
          Dance Name
          <input type='text' name='Contact0_RealFirstNameorDanceName' value=''></div>
        <div class="mailing_input">
          City
          <input type='text' name='Contact0City' value=''></div>
        <div class="mailing_input">
          State/Province
          <input type='text' name='Contact0State2' value=''></div>
        <div class="mailing_input">
          Country
          <input type='text' name='Contact0Country' value=''></div>
      </div>
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox0" checked="yes" value="105">&nbsp;NYC Shows
        &amp; Events&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox1" value="107">&nbsp;NYC Weekly Classes&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox2" checked="yes" value="109">&nbsp;NYC Area
        Workshops&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox3" value="111">&nbsp;National &amp; Int'l Workshops
        / Events&nbsp;<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox4" checked="yes" value="115">&nbsp;Ranya DVD
        Updates&nbsp;<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox5" value="117">&nbsp;Long Distance Coaching
        Interest&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="top_mailing_visible">
    <div id="visible_wrap">
      <div id="mailing_label">
        <span>Mailing List</span></div>
      <input id="top_email" type="text" value="Your E-mail Address" name="Contact0Email"
        onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your E-mai Address') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your E-mail Address';}" />
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="signup_btn" id="Submit" value="" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#top_nav div#top_mailing
{
    float: right;
    width: 351px;
    padding: 0 10px 46px 5px;
    background: url(images/top_mailing_bg.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0px #222;
}
#top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden
{
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px; 
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0;
    display: none;
}
form#top_email_form
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 135px;
}
#top_mailing div#checkboxes
{
    width: 135px;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
#top_mailing div#hidden_inputs
{
    width: 205px;
    height: 128px;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    background: url(images/hidden_inputs_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 6px;
}
#top_mailing div.mailing_input
{
    width: 205px;
    height: 14px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#top_mailing div.mailing_input input
{
    float: right;
    height: 14px;
}
#top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden span, #top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden input,
{
    float: right;
}
#top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden a
{
    color: #acffc0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#top_mailing #top_mailing_visible
{
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .9em;
    padding: 5px 0 10px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#top_mailing input#top_email
{
    color: #8c8d8d;
    background: url(images/top_mailing_field_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 163px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 4px 7px 2px;
    border: 0 none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#top_mailing div#mailing_label
{
    width: 82px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    line-height: 1em;
    float: left;
}
#top_mailing form
{
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
}
input.signup_btn
{
    background: url(images/signup_btn.png) no-repeat;
    width: 83px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
input.signup_btn:hover
{
    background-position: 0 -31px;
}
```

And here's my jQuery

```
//Top Mailing List Drop down animation
$(document).ready(function () {       
    if (jQuery.browser.msie === true) {
        jQuery('#top_mailing')
            .bind(
                "mouseenter",
                function(){
                    $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideDown('slow');
                }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
                    $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideUp('slow');
                });
    }


$('#top_mailing').hoverIntent(
    function () {
        $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideDown('slow');
    }, 
    function () {
        $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: some code or problem code hosted somewhere will greatly help in finding the problem instead of vague description.

Comment: Please post relevant code. In this case, relevant CSS, javascript and HTML. Thanks.

Comment: There's your code... you asked for it!!!

Comment: Ok, discovered the problem.  I have wrapped the <form> in two separate <div>'s in order to cause the upper portion of the <form> to be hidden until mouseover triggers the slideUP animation.  Is there a way to make the lower portion of the <form> which is visible in the #top_mailing_visible show in IE7.  It's showing in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by patrick over here: [Form wrapped in two separate DIV's not displaying in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232854/form-wrapped-in-two-separate-divs-not-displaying-in-ie7)

Answer (score 4):

For starters, you have more than one element with the same ID. That is not allowed. IDs can not be reused. If you have more than one, you need to use class.

```
id='#top_mailing'
#top_mailing
```

should be

```
class='.top_mailing'
.top_mailing
```

Fix any other repetitive ids you find, and then try again.

```
<div id="top_mailing">
<form method="POST" id="top_mailing" action="xxx">
<input id="top_mailing" type="text" value="Your E-mail Address" name="Contact0Email" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your E-mai Address') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your E-mail Address';}" />
```

Comment: Good catch.  Fixed them all and the problem persists :/

Comment: Hi Patrick.  Updated the changed #top_mailing duplicates in the code above.

Comment: Brian, you're going to get this a little at a time it looks like. Your HTML tags are not properly balanced. The 'form' tag is closing with a 'div' tag. The closing form tag is in the wrong place. Make sure everything is perfectly balanced, then let me know.

Comment: Also, not that this is technically wrong, but in your CSS, you have redundant references. Here's an example of what I mean. `#top_mailing #top_mailing_visible` Since `#top_mailing_visible` is an ID, and there can be only one of those on the entire page, there's really no need to specify that it is a descendant of `#top_mailing`. **It isn't wrong**, but it is more to take in as you're reading the CSS.

Comment: Ok, discovered the problem. I have wrapped the <form> in two separate <div>'s in order to cause the upper portion of the <form> to be hidden until mouseover triggers the slideUP animation. Is there a way to make the lower portion of the <form> which is visible in the #top_mailing_visible show in IE7. It's showing in all other browsers.

Comment: Brian - I guess we'll continue in your new post.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your JQuery & HTML for this is probably needed........ but let me throw a guess in the dark: Try setting a fixed height in CSS for your absolute-positioned div and see what happens in IE7.

**EDIT:**

It's somewhat hard to read the code because of divitis (no doubt you have your reasons) and skewed indentation but I spot one possible cause:

This element's height `form#top_mailing` is not consistent with the total of the hidden + showing elements inside it (140px + 30px).

Comment: No problem Tom.  However, I have already set a fixed height on the absolute positioned element.

Comment: Added a comment, not sure if that's it, worth a look-over.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily relevant to your question, but you have an invalid CSS selector. On the line that says `#top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden span, #top_mailing #top_mailing_hidden input,`, you have a trailing comma that could potentially cause the styles for that selector to not work.